# C random matrix with numbers between 0 and 9

Tags: c, matrix

I'm a C newbie and I'm trying to make a matrix 5x4 only with numbers between 0 and 9 where each number needs to be there 2 times (I'm trying to make the memory game). I got this code but I think that this is quite a mess and its not working, so my question is, how can I improve my code or how can I make this matrix in a different way?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MaxC 4
#define MaxL 5



int main(){


    int n1=0, n2=0, n3=0, n4=0, n5=0, n6=0, n7=0, n8=0, n9=0, n0=0;
    int i=0,j=0,r;
    int n[MaxL][MaxC];
    srand(time(NULL));

    while(i<5){
        j=0;
        while(j<4){

            r=(rand()%10);

            if(r==0 && n0<2){
                n0++;
                j++;
                n[i][j]=r;
                printf(" %3d ",n[i][j]);
            }
            if(r==1 && n1<2){
                n1++;
                j++;
                n[i][j]=r;
                printf(" %3d ",n[i][j]);
            }
            if(r==2 && n2<2){
                n2++;
                j++;
                n[i][j]=r;
                printf(" %3d ",n[i][j]);
            }
            if(r==3 && n3<2){
                n3++;
                j++;
                n[i][j]=r;
                printf(" %3d ",n[i][j]);
            }
            if(r==4 && n4<2){
                n4++;
                j++;
                n[i][j]=r;
                printf(" %3d ",n[i][j]);
            }
            if(r==5 && n5<2){
                n5++;
                j++;
                n[i][j]=r;
                printf(" %3d ",n[i][j]);
            }
            if(r==6 && n6<2){
                n6++;
                j++;
                n[i][j]=r;
                printf(" %3d ",n[i][j]);
            }
            if(r==7 && n7<2){
                n7++;
                j++;
                n[i][j]=r;
                printf(" %3d ",n[i][j]);
            }
            if(r==8 && n8<2){
                n8++;
                j++;
                n[i][j]=r;
                printf(" %3d ",n[i][j]);
            }
            if(r==9 && n9<2){
                n9++;
                j++;
                n[i][j]=r;
                printf(" %3d ",n[i][j]);
            }

        }
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do start with formatting your code properly.

Comment: Would you mind explaining "its not working"? What do you expect and what actually happens? At least you should include `time.h` to use the `time()` function.

Comment: MikeCAT im trying to print the matrix but it only gives me the first line.
never used the time.h acc, i made master mind without it :s

Comment: Hints to improve your code: `for` statement, `switch` statement, arrays, shuffling

Comment: If you don't want to use `time.h` for some reason, you should declare `time()` function by yourself before using it.

Comment: To encourage `printf()` to output its buffer data, use `fflush(stdout)` or add `'\n'` to the print statements.  I suspect code is in an infinite loop.

Comment: MikeCAT i think that this is not my real prob cuz the compiler only gives me a warning  :/

Comment: Put `n0, n1, ....` into an array indexed by `r`. That will reduce code size

Comment: @WhozCraig so insted of having the prints inside of the ifs i will only print in the end, right?

Comment: thx to everyone, my problem is solved :D

Comment: Please try to refrain from txtspk here if you can - this is not a chat-room. It is much easier if you can just write "thanks" and "because". It doesn't have to be Shakespeare, but a little effort is appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little change to make your program shorter.

I've placed n0, n1, .... into an array indexed by r.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MaxC 4
#define MaxL 5

int main()
{
    int na[10] = {0};
    int n[MaxL][MaxC], i=0;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    while(i<MaxL)
    {
        int j=0;
        while(j<MaxC)
        {
            int r = rand() % 10;
            if(na[r]<2)
            {
                ++na[r];
                n[i][j] = r;
                printf(" %3d ",n[i][j]);
                ++j;
            }
        }
        ++i;
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
   2    6    1    8 
   4    7    0    2 
   5    3    7    8 
   9    1    0    3 
   5    6    4    9
```

Your code keeps trying random number until you have had each number twice. That is not the best approach.

Instead you could initialize the matrix with the 20 numbers at fix locations and then do a random shuffle of the matrix.

Comment: Move the single-line `j++;` past the inner `printf` Also, `MaxC` and `MaxL` are there for a reason. use them for your control loops

Answer (score 1):

First off, you've placed `j++` in every `if` statement. It'll look a lot cleaner if you just leave `j++` at the end of the loop. Same goes for the `print` statement.

Second, if you could post what the program is printing out or describe **how** it's not working, that would help you get an answer to your problem. I don't see what functional issue your code has without trying it myself.

EDIT: See 4386427's answer for further ways to simplify your code.

Answer (score 1):

May I help you? You can simplify your code if you replace ten the nX variables on array. Look at this:

```
int main(){
    int c[10] = {0};
    int i=0,j=0,r;
    int n[MaxL][MaxC];
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      for(j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        do {
           r=(rand()%10);
        } while( c[r] > 2);
        ++c[r];
        n[i][j]=r;
        printf(" %3d ",n[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```